# Python: Looping issue or indentation

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, python-3.4

Python 3.4

Hi guys! I need help with Boolean operators in my program.
You have to guess a number set by the program, from 1 - 1000.
If you guess it says good job, if not it says high/low.

Use While, if/elif/else (any of them), and also a playagain loop.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import random

a = int(input("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number?\nPlease type your first guess."))
x = random.randrange(1,1000)
counter = 0
b = False
while not b:
    if a == x:
        print ("Excellent! You guessed the number in", counter1,"tries.")
        b = True
    elif a > x:
        print ("high")
        counter = counter + 1

    elif a < x:
        print ("low")
        counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: You seem to be doing it correctly already.

Comment: You don't need that `break` statement. Since you're setting `b` to `True`, the loop will not perform another iteration.

Comment: General note: to make it easier for people to help you, it's better to ask a more specific question. In this case, what is the program doing right now that needs to be different?

Comment: @mattm no break statement now. When i run the program, it either says high over and over again without stopping, or low

Comment: @Player72: See the most recent edit to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue was that you weren't prompting them in the loop.

```
import random

x = random.randrange(1,1000)    
counter = 0 

while True:
    guess = int(input("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number?\nPlease type your first guess.")) 
    if guess == x:
        print ("Excellent! You guessed the number in", counter,"tries.")
        break
    else:
        if guess > x:
            print("high")
        else:
            print("low")
        counter += 1
```

To prompt the user if they wish to play again, you'd do the following:

```
import random

x = random.randrange(1,1000)    
counter = 0 

while True:
    guess = int(input("I have a number between 1 and 1000. Can you guess my number?\nPlease type your first guess.")) 
    if guess == x:
        print ("Excellent! You guessed the number in", counter,"tries.")
        play_again = input("Type Y if you'd like to play again, or N if not")
        if play_again == 'N':
            break
    else:
        if guess > x:
            print("high")
        else:
            print("low")
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Because you only were prompting the user for a number once. You prompted the user for a number, and then entered the loop. If they're first guess wasn't right, you were never prompting again and looping infinitely. Since they could never guess again, the loop would never terminate since the first `if` condition is never satisfied.